# Why directly defined CSS class not applies?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have [this list](http://jsfiddle.net/RxBU8/):

```html
<ul class="parent">
    <li class="child">li1</li>
    <li>li2</li>
    <li>li3</li>
</ul>
```

Now if I apply

```css
.parent li {
    background-color: blue;
}
.child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

then the red background is ignored. Don't want to make it !important, but understand why class not work. If I change these selectors either to `ul li` & `.child` , or extend them to `.parent li` & `.parent .child` , then background applies. So maybe simple question: is there any rule, why this selector must be defined with a "full path"? Why it's not working when defined directly only with the class name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in [CSS selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). Short version: the most-specific selector wins.